# What is role the of url in async function in web scrapping

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, axios, javascript-objects

I am working on web scrapping and I came across one scenario where I am get confused about arrow key function,I am unable to understand why url is used twice and how it is actual working, I know it is advanced javascript but I need some explanation to understand this completely.

first Url in arrow function:

```
const fethHtml = async url => {
```

Second url pass in axios.get

```
await axios.get(url);
```

const fethHtml = async url => {

```
const axios = require("axios").default;

const fethHtml = async url => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(url);
    return data;
  } catch {
    console.error(
      `ERROR: An error occurred while trying to fetch the URL: ${url}`
    );
  }
};
```

My question is what url is indicating here is it variable or function and why it is called twice, I didn't found any explanation anywhere.

Comment: Variables are not called. They're created and referenced.

Comment: `async url => {` creates a variable to be used inside the `fetchHtmlz function, whereas `axios.get(url)` passes that variable into the `axios.get` function. This is not unusual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const fethHtml = async url => {`

url is just arguments. (ex:google.com)

then pass the arguments to axios to get resposne.

`await axios.get(url);`